# A way to store performance testing results

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I frequently run performance tests on the system I work on (using JMeter and k6), and I'd like to store the results somewhere for further analysis and comparison. The catch is that the system has various available configurations and parameters, and ideally I'd like to be able to compare and filter the results across them.

For example, not only would I like to see the usual avg, median, percentiles, but I'd also like to filter them by "database used", "db insertion algorithm", "number of instances", etc. Overall, there are a lot of different parameters I tweak and I'd like to be able to see the system configuration related to a particular test run.

The current approach I use is simply a giant Excel spreadsheet with each parameter in a dedicated column. It's not unusable, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I think both [JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2/) and [k6](https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/influxdb-+-grafana/) support sending test results to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) so you can use it as a centralized storage.

JMeter's [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) allows specifying application name, test title, event tags, etc. and all these can be used as filters in i.e. [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) dashboards

Comment: I'm currently using Influx for time series, but I wonder if it's a good fit for the test summaries. Essentially, I need to compare the summaries of test runs and also some comments about the runs themselves. Something like "A run on date-time, 2 instances, avg, median, and a human-written comment with notes, potential errors". For me, Influx seems more suited for things like the rate of requests, duration, etc over time.